How to Solve the Inequality $(-4-x) < \sqrt{x^2 + 4x - 5}$?
I am struggling with solving the following inequality:  $ -4 - x < \sqrt{x^2 + 4x - 5} $
I have tried some methods but still cannot find a clear solution. I know that based on the equation $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x - 5}$, we can analyze that $(x \leq -5)$ or $(x \geq 1)$. However, I am unsure how to proceed from here to solve the inequality.
Could someone please give me some hints on how to solve this inequality?

Why are you asking for a complete solution and not hints? It is expected that you are interested in solving your own problems?

HINT
Let consider two cases:

$-4-x <0$ (the inequlity is trivially true, when RHS exists)
$-4-x \ge 0$ (we can square both sides)


As you noticed, $x^2+4x-5\geq 0\iff x\geq 1 \text{ or } x\leq -5 $ so that the square root (and thus the inequality) only makes sense in that case.
The RHS is non-negative, so if the LHS is negative, we are finished. We would need  $$-4-x< 0\iff x> -4$$
By the above, $x\geq 1$ is a set of solutions.
If $x\leq -4$ then both sides are positive and the inequality is equivalent to the one obtained squaring both sides. Doing so, we get $$x^2+8x+16<x^2+4x-5\iff 4x<-21\iff x<-\dfrac{21}{4} $$
Given that $-\dfrac{21}{4}<-5$ all these are solutions.
We conclude that the inequality is satisfied iff $x\in \left(-\infty,-\dfrac{21}{4}\right)\cup [-1,+\infty)$.

We first require $\sqrt{x^2 + 4x-5} \in\mathbb R$ or in other terms $x^2 + 4x-5 \geq 0$. That can be written as $(x+5)(x-1) \geq 0$ which gives that the solution set must be a subset of $$(-\infty, -5] \cup [1,\infty) \tag1$$
Let's now do casework:
$1$: If $x> -4$ then the left hand is negative while the right hand is non-negative by definition; Then $x>-4$ works but taking its intersection with $(1)$ yields that our solution set from this case is $[1, \infty) \tag 2$
$1$: If $x \le -4$. Then we can just square both sides since they're non-negative which doesn't reverse the sign of the inequality: $$\begin{align}(4+x)^2 < x^2 + 4x - 5 \\ \implies 16 + 8x < 4x -5 \\ \implies 4x<-21 \\ \implies x<-\frac{21}4\end{align}$$
This last inequality is stricter than what our case assumption was: so we get the solution as $\left(-\infty, -\frac{21}4\right)$. Taking its intersection with $(1)$ we get the solution set from this case as $\left(-\infty, -\frac{21}4\right) \tag3$
Thus our solution set is $(2) \cup (3)$ ie $$x \in \left(-\infty, -\frac{21}4\right) \cup [1,\infty)$$
